# Multi-dimensional numpy.expand_dims in numba

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba

Due to the absence of `np.einsum` and `np.newaxis` in numba, I would like a convenient way to perform `np.expand_dims` for multiple axes while being able to `numba.njit` over the function. Two solutions which I **can't** get `njit`'ed:

```py
def expand_dims(arr, axes):
    for ax in axes:
        arr = np.expand_dims(arr, ax)
    return arr

def expand_dims2(arr, axes):
    shape_list = list(arr.shape)
    for ax in axes:
        shape_list.insert(ax, 1)
    return arr.reshape(tuple(shape_list))
```

with `axes` being an iterable of axis indices which should be created.

Is there a nice way to do this while being able to `njit` the function? Otherwise the code gets messy very quickly.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the dimensions before calling the Numba function? I generally have to wrap njit-ed functions to do operations like that before calling them. Also, the semantics of your function are confusing...For example, if `arr` has shape `(3, 4)`, calling `expand_dims(arr, (1, 2))` would give shape `(3, 1, 1, 4)`, whereas `expand_dims(arr, (2, 1))` would give `(3, 1, 4, 1)`. Moreover, `expand_dims(arr, (3, 2, 1))` would not work (for now it just gives deprecation warning), while `expand_dims(arr, (1, 2, 3))` would run fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It may very well be that these functions are not waterproof. I'm rather looking for a general way do achieve similar functionality in numba. Reshaping the arrays before does not match my usecase, as I need to multiply arrays together in different ways, all in the same function. In the end, I basically want the most convenient way to get as close to `np.einsum` functionality as possible, multiplying arbitrary array axes together.

Comment: Another important point is that I want to do this on intermediate arrays inside a larger function which should be `njit`'ed. So changing the dimensions "outside" numba is not possible.

Comment: If you want to "emulate" einsum, you will probably get the most out of Numba by simply writing out the (nested) loops (and maybe using `prange`/`parallel=True`). Doing matrix multiplication and then summing axes will likely be slower than einsum and will take more memory too...

Comment: I was somehow hoping that `njit`'ing a function would get rid of temporary arrays and the overhead of them materializing at once in memory (similar to what [jax](https://github.com/google/jax) does). If that is not the case with numba, writing explicit loops may be the only option.